# compare similar items nested in a list, and removing them

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, maya

I am trying to find duplicates in relationship and omit them from my list. I have tried nested if statements, but I haven't gotten the right solution yet.

```
list = [[u'polySurface5.e[4]', u'polySurface5.e[1]', .5], [u'polySurface5.e[8]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', .9], [u'polySurface5.e[1]', u'polySurface5.e[4]', .5], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[9]', 1.2], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', 0] ]
```

in the following list, I want to remove "doubles", and values where that last item is 0. I want to end up with something like this:

```
newlist = [[u'polySurface5.e[4]', u'polySurface5.e[1]', .5], [u'polySurface5.e[8]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', .9], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[9]', 1.2] ]
```

in which way can i compare [u'polySurface5.e[4]', u'polySurface5.e[1]', .5] with [u'polySurface5.e[1]', u'polySurface5.e[4]', .5] and remove any occurrence after the first one?

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = [[u'polySurface5.e[4]', u'polySurface5.e[1]', .5], [u'polySurface5.e[8]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', .9], [u'polySurface5.e[1]', u'polySurface5.e[4]', .5], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[9]', 1.2], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', 0] ]

new_list = []
my_set = set()
for sublist in my_list:
    if sublist[2] != 0:
        frozen_sub = frozenset(sublist)
        if not frozen_sub in my_set:
            new_list.append(sublist)
            my_set.add(frozen_sub)
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
[[u'polySurface5.e[4]', u'polySurface5.e[1]', 0.5], [u'polySurface5.e[8]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', 0.9], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[9]', 1.2]]
```

Notice that I changed the name of the original list `list` to `my_list`. I did it because `list` is a keyword in Python, but by calling an `object` `list` you are shadowing it. Check this out:

```
>>> list((1,2,3))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list = [3,4,5]
>>> list((6,7,8))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Edit: Answering the follow up post.

`set` is a data structure that contains only unique items and the items have no order. For example:

```
>>> set([1,2,2,4,4])
set([1, 2, 4])
>>> set([1,2,4]) == set([4,4,4,1,2])
True
```

`frozenset` is data structure similar to set, but it is different. `set` is mutable while `frozenset` is not; that is we can add things to set, but not to `frozenset`. However, `frozenset` is hashable, while `set` is not. That is `fozenset` can be a key in a `dictionary' or an element in a set.

Mutability:

```
>>> b = set([1,2,3])
>>> b.add(6)
>>> b
set([1, 2, 3, 6])
>>> d = frozenset([1,2,3])
>>> d.add(6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Hashability:

```
>>> b = set([1,2])
>>> d = set([5,3])
>>> g = set([b,d])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>> b = frozenset([1,2])
>>> d = frozenset([5,3])
>>> g = set([b,d])
>>> g
set([frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([3, 5])])
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! works exactly as i needed. I am trying to follow the logic 

i understand the sublist, removing values that have 0, and then testing for membership. what is my_set's function?

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[u'polySurface5.e[4]', u'polySurface5.e[1]', .5], [u'polySurface5.e[8]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', .9], [u'polySurface5.e[1]', u'polySurface5.e[4]', .5], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[9]', 1.2], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', 0]]
# remove [...,0]
l = filter(lambda i: i[-1] != 0, l)
# sort keys (1st and 2nd field)
l = [sorted(i[:-1]) + i[-1:] for i in l]
# uniques
add_if_unique = lambda res, x: (res + [x]) if x not in res else res
l = reduce(add_if_unique, l, [])
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the required result.

Comment: @mhawke, I forgot to sort the keys. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner?

```
l = [[u'polySurface5.e[4]', u'polySurface5.e[1]', .5],
     [u'polySurface5.e[8]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', .9],
     [u'polySurface5.e[1]', u'polySurface5.e[4]', .5],
     [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[9]', 1.2],
     [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[2]', 0]]

newlist = [list(member) for member in set([tuple(sorted(x[:-1]) + x[-1:]) for x in l if x[-1] != 0])]

print newlist
[[u'polySurface5.e[1]', u'polySurface5.e[4]', 0.5], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[8]', 0.9], [u'polySurface5.e[2]', u'polySurface5.e[9]', 1.2]]
```